# are repeated links to an user's blog considered spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

for example see those answers:

[What exactly is NoSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173082/what-exactly-is-nosql/2770402#2770402)

[When NOT to use Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634955/when-not-to-use-cassandra/2677850#2677850)

[nosql modeling : howto (digg as an example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611362/nosql-modeling-howto-digg-as-an-example/2677881#2677881)

[What is 'document data store' and 'key-value data store'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568245/what-is-document-data-store-and-key-value-data-store/2589050#2589050)

[Which NoSQL storage to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729981/which-nosql-storage-to-choose/2759200#2759200)

Comment: @CodyGray I read it and flagged those posts but they all got declined,this question didn't mention those examples

Comment: The section "Are users allowed to promote their website in an answer?" in the answer to that question seems to contain the answer to your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can link to their own blogs, as long as any affiliation with the blog is mentioned, and it's relevant to the answer.

I couldn't evaluate the relevance, but the user could be a little more pro-active in mentioning it's his own blog. I've taken the liberty of editing his posts.